# Magento :Create community module

Tags: magento, module

I downloaded megento with composer and installed it,ther app/code directory for creating module, So i just created this directory and my module directory like this :

[image]

And etc\modules as the same,i created it. But the module its not in Magento module list. The app/code/community/Shareino/SyncModule/etc/config file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_SyncModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Shareino_SyncModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The app/etc/modules/Shareino_SyncModule like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shareino_SyncModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Shareino_SyncModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But this module isnot in magento's module list.

Comment: Please check permission of folder and file. Folder should have 755 and file should have 644 permission.

Comment: Tnx @SunnyRathod but it didn't work

Comment: I dont knwo what is wrong there but you can use `http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/` link to create module and this is always work. I have personally use this.